# Sub menu not working properly

Tags: html, css

I can't get the sub menu be right on top of the parent on tab2. I mean that when i hover just below tab2 the sub menu apears. I use my own made buttons (pictures). And could someone tidy up that css code in the demo? Thank you very much :) Here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/3Lhe7/

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
max-width: 1000px;
text-align: right;
/*text-align: center;*/
}

.bg {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: -5000;
}

#navigation {
clear: both;
width: 60%; 
margin: 0 auto; 
border: 0px;
text-align: left;
position: absolute;
top:  65%;
left: 20%;  
height: 90px;
min-width:830px;
max-width:1000px;
}

#navigation ul {
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#navigation ul li {
display: inline;
position: relative;
float: left;
list-style-type: none;
height: 45px;
}

#navigation li ul {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
display: none;
position: absolute;
}

#navigation ul li a {
list-style: none;
display: block;
width: 150px;
height: 90px;
padding: 0px;
}

#navigation ul li ul {
display: none;  
}

#navigation ul li:hover ul {
display: block;
bottom: 100%;
}

#submenu {  
list-style: none;
display: block;
width: 150px;
height: 45px;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: post your code/working demo

Comment: Could you add accessible image src to your code demo?

Comment: For tidy up code use `TidyUp` button in jsfiddle :)

Comment: I feel it is right top of the tab2

Comment: What's you testing browser? I use Google Chrome 25.0.1364.152 m and it is right on top

Comment: It is on top, but when i hover just under the tab2 it opens sub menu. It should only open when i hover on parent. I use chrome Version 25.0.1364.97m

Comment: @DevangRathod i dont know where i did a mistake or something

Comment: Remove or decrease height of `#navigation ul li a`

Comment: @sємsєм I don't know how to :/ but in the demo there are pic borders, so you can use them :)

Comment: @Rokas Stankaitis you are welcome(prasau) :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your reasoning behind making `#submenu`'s height 45px, but changing this (the `height` property) to `0` seems to solve the problem.

```
#submenu {  
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Lhe7/4/